# Failed to call Activator.CreateInstance with GraphQL and .NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, graphql

When executing a query I get this error: `{"failed to call activator.createinstance. type: api.graphql.lessonquery"}`

The constructor of Lessonquery is as follows:

```
private readonly AppDbContext _db;

public LessonQuery(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _db = dbContext;
    }
```

And I have added `services.AddSingleton<AppDbContext>();` to the `ConfigureServices()` in startup.cs

I include my LessonQuery class in the schema like this

```
public LessonSchema()
{
    this._schema = Schema.For(@"

    type Lesson {
        id: ID,
        title: String,
        level: String,
        exercises : [String]
    }

    type Query {
        lessons: [Lesson],
        lesson(id: ID): [Lesson]
    }


", _ =>
    {
        _.Types.Include<LessonQuery>();

    });
```

I am looking for a way to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default GraphQL .NET uses `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the classes, but that requires a parameterless constructor. If you want to use Dependency Injection with GraphQL .NET, you need to assign the Schema an `IServiceProvider`.

```cs
public LessonSchema(IServiceProvider sp)
{
    this._schema = Schema.For(@"

    type Lesson {
        id: ID,
        title: String,
        level: String,
        exercises : [String]
    }

    type Query {
        lessons: [Lesson],
        lesson(id: ID): [Lesson]
    }


", _ =>
    {
        _.ServiceProvider = sp;
        _.Types.Include<LessonQuery>();

    });
```

Edit: I just found out that the behvior was different in Version 2.4.0. Here you need to create an `IDependencyResolver` instead of an `IServiceProvider`. THe easiest way to connect the exsisting `IServiceProvider` from ASP.NET Core to GraphQL.NET is to use `FuncDependencyResolver` like so:

```cs
public LessonSchema(IServiceProvider sp)
{
    this._schema = Schema.For(@"

    type Lesson {
        id: ID,
        title: String,
        level: String,
        exercises : [String]
    }

    type Query {
        lessons: [Lesson],
        lesson(id: ID): [Lesson]
    }


", _ =>
    {
        _.DependencyResolver = new FuncDependencyResolver(t => sp.GetService(t));
        _.Types.Include<LessonQuery>();

    });
```

Comment: My schema type doesn't seem to have a field ServiceProvider, the class I use is GgraphQL.Types.Schema

Comment: The solution I provided was for GraphQL.NET 3 and not 2.4. I edited the post to include a solution for 2.4.

Comment: I'm using 2.4. With change suggested by you, when I try to instantiate the schema in the app like `LessonSchema schema = new LessonSchema(...)`, what I need to pass here? Expected is  `IServiceProvider`. But I'm not sure what should I pass to it. @Rain336